# Обновление содержимого блока без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Допустим есть страница index.html
Есть блок 
Есть навигационное меню 
В блоке с классом content много блоков с различным контентом
Как сделать обновление контента внутри блока content в рамках одной страницы index.html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Для решения данной задачи вам понадобится [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). 
Самое простое решение - отправлять запрос при необходимости обновить блок.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType
}).done(function(answer){
      $('.ClassBlock').replaceWith(answer);
});
```

реализация на `done` может отличатся.

- **url** - адрес где находится обработчик.
- **data** - данные которые будут отправлены в запросе.
- **dataType** - тип данных которые ждем обратно.

`.success(function() { alert("Успешное выполнение"); })
.error(function() { alert("Ошибка выполнения"); })
.complete(function() { alert("Завершение выполнения"); });`